# How to cancel a password reset in AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-cognito, reset-password

I use AWS Cognito as the authentication provider in a React application. I noticed an issue with the Reset Password flow:

Imagine I forget my password and request a password reset. Cognito sends me an email with a security code. Then, I remember the password and don't want to change it any more. I can't because even if I log in with the correct password, it still sends me to the Set New Password page. It seems like a security concern because anyone can force other users to reset their password as long as they know their email address.

Is that by design in Cognito or is it a bug in my use of Cognito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to verify how the forgot password/authentication flow have been implemented within your app. The Reset Password page should not send the `NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED` MFA challenge, nor change the user's status to need a new password in the user pool.

The [ForgotPassword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ForgotPassword.html) API call generates the reset code for the user, whereas the [ConfirmForgotPassword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ConfirmForgotPassword.html) API call accepts the code and allows the user to change the password. These API calls do not change the user's status for resetting their password, or create the [NEW_PASSWORD_REQUIRED](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_RespondToAuthChallenge.html#API_RespondToAuthChallenge_RequestParameters) MFA challenge.

For completeness, there is no way to cancel the password reset code once it's been sent out. [The code is valid for 24 hours](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/limits.html), although sending another code will invalidate the first.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not trying to cancel the password reset code. I want to not force the user to change the password once the code is sent. It sounds like I need to review our app.

Comment: Thanks for the sanity check. I figured it out: we were using the AdminResetPassword API call instead of ForgotPassword. It behaves similar apart from the issue above.